csvsimple filter not working with tabularx
It is needed to compile the following basic code using a filter for tabularx and csvsimple:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3,filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc,fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{datos.csv}
Name, Lastname, Score
Ana, Ana, 10
BAna, BAna, 11
CAna, CAna, 14
DAna, DAna, 15
\end{filecontents*}
        
\section{Total de Alumnos Solamente Aprobados}
    
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{llc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Nombres} & \textbf{Apellidos} & \textbf{Nota} \\
        \midrule
        \csvreader[%
        filter fp = {\nota>11},%
        late after line={\\},%
        late after last line={\\\bottomrule},
        ]
        {datos.csv}
        {1=\nombre, 2=\apellido, 3=\nota}%
        {\nombre & \apellido & \nota}
\end{tabularx}
        
\end{document}

The error log show the message:
foro_103_tabularx.tex: error: 33: Argument of \use_none:nn has an extra }. {\nombre & \apellido & \nota}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3,filecontents,longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc,fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{datos.csv}
name,lastname,score
Ana,Ana,10
Bana,Bana,11
Cana,Cana,14
Dana,Dana,15
\end{filecontents*}
        
\section{Total de Alumnos Solamente Aprobados}
    
\begin{tabular}{llc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Nombres} & \textbf{Apellidos} & \textbf{Nota} \cr
        \midrule
        \csvreader[%
        %filter fp = {\nota>11},%
        filter test = \ifnumgreater{\csvcoliii}{12},
        late after line={\cr},%
        late after last line={\cr\bottomrule},
        ]
        {datos.csv}
        {}%
        {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{tabular}
        
\end{document}


If this is an answer (which siolve your problem) than you can accept them and by this info0rm audience here, that your problem is solved. It will be helpful for people with similar problem, that you add short description what you change in it (in comparison to code in question) that now works.
